# How to stop Images Blending at anytime and save image to file

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics

I have created an application that blends 2 images from one to another.See below:-

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

class Frame extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Image MeSmaller1;
private Image MeSmaller2;
private Timer timeBlend;
private float alpha;

public Frame() {
    loadImages();
    initTimer();
}

private void loadImages() {
    MeSmaller1 = new ImageIcon("MeSmaller1.jpg").getImage();
    MeSmaller2 = new ImageIcon("MeSmaller2.jpg").getImage();
}

private void initTimer() {
    timeBlend = new Timer(1000, this);
    timeBlend.start();
    alpha = 1f;
}

private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2Dim = (Graphics2D) g;
    // below sets the size of picture
    BufferedImage buffImage = new BufferedImage(400, 600,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D gBuffI = buffImage.createGraphics();
    AlphaComposite aComp = AlphaComposite.getInstance(
            AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha);
    // decides where images are drawn in JFrame
    gBuffI.drawImage(MeSmaller1, -2, 0, null);
    gBuffI.setComposite(aComp);
    gBuffI.drawImage(MeSmaller2, 0, -7, null);
    g2Dim.drawImage(buffImage, 10, 10, null);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    doDrawing(g);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    alpha -= 0.1;
    if (alpha <= 0) {
        alpha = 0;
        timeBlend.stop();
        System.out.println("Morph Finished please restart.");
    }
    repaint();
}
```

How do I add a button to this that when clicked will stop the image blending at any point clicked (when clicked again blend will resume), then how do I add a button that will save blended image to file when clicked (at any point wanted to save) I hope this isn't asking too much at once.

Comment: Timer#stop and Timer#restart

Comment: What I would do, is render the result to a BufferedImage and paint that to the screen, then you could just saw the BufferedImage

Comment: I just know what I need to do isn't that complex but my head just can't get itself to think the right way about this in programming terms :-(

Comment: I have now add 3 buttons to the code a Start Blend (of images) a Stop Blend and a save image file with 3 classes connected implementing ActionListeners. Just need to work out now how to get the buttons to do what I want !!!